# wpf binding contextmenu

Tags: wpf, data-binding, contextmenu

in my main view, I have a slider that can be used to scale the application.

```
<Slider x:Name="zoomSlider" VerticalAlignment="Center" Value="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" TickFrequency="0.2" TickPlacement="Both" Minimum="0.5" Maximum="3" SmallChange="0.5" LargeChange="0.5" Width="100" />
```

and every control is scale-transformed accordingly:

```
<Controls:AutoHidePanel AutoHide="False" AutoFade="True" Height="50" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Controls:AutoHidePanel.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform
                ScaleX="{Binding Value, ElementName=zoomSlider}"
                ScaleY="{Binding Value, ElementName=zoomSlider}"/>
            </Controls:AutoHidePanel.LayoutTransform>
            <MenuControl />
        </Controls:AutoHidePanel>
```

This works fine: like this every control in my windows scales fine.

Now, the MenuControl is a view that has a splitbutton, and this splitbutton uses a context menu to display sub items. The button itself scales too, but the context menu does not scale.

How can I make sure that this context menu scales together with its button control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile I found a solution. I just set the data context of the context menu to its parent data context like:

```
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext}">
```